# Is the default address of an undefined array always a valid address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, undefined, memory-address

In my system, an undefined pointer has a default value of 0x00000000.

```
void Demo()
{
    char cData;
    char *pExamplePtr;
    char pExampleArray[4];

    &cData <--- Address is 0x12345678
    pExamplePtr  <--- Value of pointer is 0x00000000
    pExampleArray[0] <--- Address is ???
}
```

What is the default address of pExampleArray? Is it 0x00000000 or does it have some valid address like cData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer pExamplePtr does indeed have a valid address. Maybe what you meant to say is that it is not pointing to anything and hence the 0x00000000 but that's not necessarily the case.

Also in regards with `pExampleArray[4]`, this is an array, not a pointer and it does indeed have a vaild address as is the case with your first variable.

Comment: That is what I meant to say. This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. `pExamplePtr` is uninitialized, so it doesn't necessarily point to `0`.
2. `pExampleArray` is an array, not a pointer, so it doesn't "point" anywhere either.  If you were to use `pExampleArray` in an expression, it would decay into a pointer to its first element - the equivalent of `&pExampleArray[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The address of `pExampleArray` object declared below:

```
char pExampleArray[4];
```

is `&pExampleArray` and it is a valid address.

The address of `pExamplePtr` object declared below:

```
char *pExamplePtr;
```

is `&pExamplePtr` and it is a valid address, different than `NULL`. You seem to confuse the pointer value, which is `pExamplePtr` and is indeterminate before initialization or assignment and the address of the pointer object.